# в intellij Idea перечеркнут метод

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, hibernate, spring-mvc

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

createCriteria перечеркнут что это может быть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это значит что метод был проаннотирован `@deprecated`, т.е. он устарел и может быть даже удалён в следующих версиях библиотеки.

Вы можете нажать <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + *клик по методу*, там может быть написана информация что предпочтительнее использовать. Или изучить документацию к библиотеке.

Вы можете использовать этот метод, но будьте аккуратны, возможны проблемы.

Answer (score 2):

Это значит, что в используемом API данный метод (класс) объявлен устаревшим - deprecated. Есть более новая версия с аналогичной (но, как правило, улучшенной) функциональностью и другим именем или же данный метод исключен из текущего API за ненадобностью, но оставлен для совместимости).

Вы можете продолжать использовать устаревшие методы, если требуется обратная совместимость с прошлым API или использовать предложенную замену, если такой совместимости не требуется. Так же есть небольшая вероятность, что в дальнейшем такой метод будет вовсе исключен из будущих API, что приведет к неработоспособности программы на таких API.