# Можно ли зачеркнуть текст в коде pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Мне нужно зачеркнуть текст в коде в pycharm, подскажите пожалуйста может кто нибудь знает.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "зачеркнуть"?

Comment: Не нужно зачеркивать текст в коде. Какая конкретно проблема у вас, зачем вам что-то зачеркивать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачеркнуть текст в PyCharm без каких-либо дополнений невозможно. Единственный подходящий для вас ответ это -- [в intellij Idea перечеркнут метод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546983/%D0%B2-intellij-idea-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4)